# Pipe Future result to self

Tags: akka

Is it safe to pipe a Future's result directly to 'self'?

Within an actor:

```
Future(hardWork()).pipeTo(self)
```

Or must we assign to a val:

```
val me = self
Future(hardWork()).pipeTo(me)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in your code is safe, because you are not closing over anything. You are just calling a regular method `pipeTo` and passing in a regular parameter. Only closing over something (like you did in your own answer) might be dangerous, but in the case of `self` there is no danger because `self` is not mutable.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently 'self' is safe, so no need for the `val me = self`.

```
// Completely safe, "self" is OK to close over
// and it's an ActorRef, which is thread-safe
Future { expensiveCalculation() } onComplete { f => self ! f.value.get }
```

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/general/jmm.html#Actors_and_shared_mutable_state

Comment: Yes - `implicit final val self = context.self`